# My response.php page is working for one page and the same is not working for another

Tags: php, ajax, response

Here I am showing network details related to content-length.
For one page content-length - 165
For another page content-length - 0

```
Request URL: https://www.jg.com/tabs/responsesolarcustomercare.php
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 

Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 09 Nov 2018 10:38:01 GMT
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Apache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 165
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie: PHPSESSID=YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
Host: www.jg.com
Origin: https://www.jg.com
Referer: https://www.jg.com/tabs/jsm.php
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
actionsolarcustomercare: add
custname: sfdsf
village: 
mandal: 
district: 
state: 
custphone: 
po_num: 
company: 
compdetails: 
damagedetails: 
servicerep: 
workdetails: 
status:
```

and for other page it is

```
 Request URL: https://www.jg.com/tabs/responsesolarcustomercare.php
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 103.24.201.24:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 09 Nov 2018 10:39:07 GMT
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Apache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Cookie: PHPSESSID=yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
Host: www.junnagroup.com
Origin: https://www.jg.com
Referer: https://www.jg.com/tabs/lalitha.php
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

I got this code while running,
and Unable to identify where the problem exists.

Comment: Perhaps show a minimum of code instead of having us guessing? For all we know *you* are sending those headers as they are.

Answer (score 0):

@lalitha I can see host is different on both the request headers, also in second request you are not sending any post data and that's the reason your content length is 0.

We can help you if you can provide bit of your code.